# Several lists of dictionaries to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am pulling data from an API and it returns a list of dictionaries for each entry that I need to put into a pandas DataFrame. What makes this difficult is that the dictionaries that are pulled are always different.

3 examples:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'value': '1'},
 {'name': 'B', 'value': 'DateTimeValue'},
 {'name': 'C', 'value': '15'}]

[{'name': 'A', 'value': '2'},
 {'name': 'D', 'value': 'StringValue'},
 {'name': 'C', 'value': '15'}]

[{'name': 'A', 'value': '5'},
 {'name': 'B', 'value': 'DateTimeValue'},
 {'name': 'C', 'value': '19'},
 {'name': 'F', 'value': '25.123'}]
```

I need the 'name' values to be the columns in the DF and the 'value' values to be the rows. In the final application I will need to pull a few hundred of these at a time in a for loop.

The closest I got was creating several one line dataframes in a for loop and trying to merge them. However, the merge just created new columns with _y and _x. I need the dataframe to only create new columns when a new name appears, such as F above.

Here's what I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A']) # A is the only common column 

for dict in dict_list:

    data = getdata(API_stuff = ApiStuff, dicts = dict) #returns one list of dicts

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict) #get the data of one dict
    df1 = df1.transpose() 
    df1.reset_index(inplace=True) 
    df1 = df1.drop(columns= ['index'])
    df1.columns = df1.loc[0] # makes the column names the dict 'names'
    df1.drop(df1.index[0],inplace=True) # drop the duplicate row
    df1.index = ['Message-ID']
    # the above code creates a one row dataframe with the 'name' values as columns

    df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='A', how='outer') # merge one df on the previous ones
```

The output is the following:

```
   A  B  C  A_x  D  C_x  A_y  B_x  C_y  F  
0  1  DT 15
1           2   SV  15
2                         5   DT    19  25.123
```

With NaN's in the blank spaces

I need the output to be

```
   A    B    C    D     F   
0  1   DT   15   NaN   NaN
1  2   NaN  15   SV    NaN      
2  5   DT   19   NaN   25.123
```

I know there is a better way to do this but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor can handle this if you provide it in the correct shape, something like:

```
In [8]: dict_list
Out[8]:
[[{'name': 'A', 'value': '1'},
  {'name': 'B', 'value': 'DateTimeValue'},
  {'name': 'C', 'value': '15'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'value': '2'},
  {'name': 'D', 'value': 'StringValue'},
  {'name': 'C', 'value': '15'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'value': '5'},
  {'name': 'B', 'value': 'DateTimeValue'},
  {'name': 'C', 'value': '19'},
  {'name': 'F', 'value': '25.123'}]]

In [9]: pd.DataFrame([{d['name']:d['value'] for d in ds} for ds in dict_list])
Out[9]:
   A              B   C            D       F
0  1  DateTimeValue  15          NaN     NaN
1  2            NaN  15  StringValue     NaN
2  5  DateTimeValue  19          NaN  25.123
```